# Symfony 2 migration to live server issues

Tags: symfony, symfony1, composer-php, vendor

I'm new to Symfony, and know very little. I have just been handed a project that works on my local machine but I have just moved it to a live server and some parts are now broken.

I have done the following:

```
php composer.phar update
```

(Not sure what that does, but it outputs the following)

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
```

with this error:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                       
The "https://packagist.org/p/jms/parser-lib.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1    404 Not Found)
```

When I navigate to a certain part of the website, I get a "500 Internal Server Error"

My apache error log contains the following:

```
[Wed May 01 11:40:58 2013] [error] [client 88.289.76.212] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Bundle\\Bundle' not found in /var/www/html/newsletters/src/Imagine/NewsletterBundle/ImagineNewsletterBundle.php on line 9
[Wed May 01 11:45:19 2013] [error] [client 88.289.80.249] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Failed to write cache file "/var/www/html/newsletters/app/cache/prod/classes.php".' in /var/www/html/newsletters/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassCollectionLoader.php:205\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/newsletters/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassCollectionLoader.php(122): Symfony\\Component\\ClassLoader\\ClassCollectionLoader::writeCacheFile('/var/www/html/n...', '<?php  ????name...')\n#1 /var/www/html/newsletters/app/bootstrap.php.cache(756): Symfony\\Component\\ClassLoader\\ClassCollectionLoader::load(Array, '/var/www/html/n...', 'classes', false, false, '.php')\n#2 /var/www/html/newsletters/web/app.php(19): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->loadClassCache()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/newsletters/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassCollectionLoader.php on line 205, referer: http://newsletters.imagine-publishing.co.uk/web/
[Wed May 01 11:45:40 2013] [error] [client 68.289.78.46] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Can anyone offer some advice on any action that I may have not performed to get the website working on a new server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hide IPs, paths and all sensible information from your log when you ask a question. :-) I think you need to run `check.php` from the app directory in your remote host, it will tell you if Symphony's configuration is ok.

Comment: They are fake ip's ;) I did run check.php and it didnt throw up anything major. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Yep, you can have a look to your app/logs/prod.log file to see if there's something interesting.

Comment: Bingo. Looks like my database connection is failing. That database is on a different server and I guess that server doesnt like external connections

Answer (score 2):

First empty your cache: `sudo rm -r app/cache/*`

If that doen not work, check your cache permissions. You can check if the permissions are the problem by doing `sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache`. If that solves the problem, you can put some time in setting up acl properly  ([Symfony Docs => Installation => Configuration and Setup](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup))

Comment: Ok, tried both of your suggestions but no luck :( Can you tell me how i make sure all the vendors are installed?

Comment: Wel it looks like the jms-parser-lib dependency is failing. Can you post the entry for this lib in your composer.json?